# JMeter correct location to input a web url? - (Response time required)

Tags: java, jmeter

JMeter correct location to input a web url?

1. Im new to Jmeter and need to get the reponse of a given url
2. I need to use the URL address and not the IP address
3. Is the following setup correct?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is correct!

Comment: @Jahan thanks so much for your help! is the initial handshake (first test) always higher in MS?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is fine, if hostname is blank it will be populated from the HTTP Request Defaults (same for the other fields). You can override the "defaults" on HTTP Request level if required.

Few more recommendations:

1. In the "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request Defaults tick "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" and "Parallel Downloads" boxes, this way JMeter will request extra resources which are referenced in the HTML like images, scripts and styles (this is what real browsers do when rendering the pages)

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]
2. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan. Real browsers download aforementioned resources, but they do it only once, on subsequent requests images and so on are being returned form browser cache. HTTP Cache manager represents this cache and respects the relevant control headers
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) which handles user sessions and deals with cookie-based authentication
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send browser-like headers like [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), etc.

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) for above configurations explained in details.

Comment: I agree that you need to check "Retrieve All Embedded Browsers" and "Parallel Downloads". 

But in case of measuring the performance of server-side, is it still required to check those boxes?